# Sandbox solution getting error on on prem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sandbox-solution, feature-activation, feature-receiver

Sandbox solution gives me error :

> Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper’s Execute
>   method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has
>   occurred

from below code.

CODE:

```
  public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
            {
                SPFieldLookup fldLookupField = null;
                SPList SourceList = null;
                SPWeb RootWeb = null;
                try
                {

                    object obj = properties.Feature.Parent;

                    if (obj is SPWeb)
                    {
                        SPWeb web = obj as SPWeb;

                        // Getting Clients List 
                        SourceList = web.Lists["Source List"];
                        fldLookupField = (SPFieldLookup)web.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("lookUP column");
                        var c = fldLookupField.SchemaXml.ToString();
                        fldLookupField.SchemaXml = fldLookupField.SchemaXml.Replace("List=\"{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\"", string.Format("List=\"{0}\"", SourceList.ID.ToString("B")));
                        c = fldLookupField.SchemaXml.ToString();
                        fldLookupField.LookupWebId = SourceList.ParentWeb.ID;
                        fldLookupField.Update(true);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    RootWeb.Dispose();
                }
     }
```

Not getting exception in catch also. Code working good but on share point page gives error.

Can any one help me out as soon as possible ?

Comment: May be not related but RootWeb is always null and Dispose is called on it in finally.